# How to extract data from a .msg file in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently struggling with the following issue:

I'm trying to improve some process at work, which involves organizing large amounts of project emails (.msg), stored in a folder. Files need to be renamed from 'Message.msg' to 'DateSent-from Sender-Message.msg'.

Now the renaming is easy to do with an excel macro, but I'm really struggling to get the data I need from the .msg.

Is there any way for excel to read some information from a .msg file? Everything I tried so far has failed. I'm interested in the Sender and Date Sent.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: Open it as a text stream, both the Sender and the Sent date should be readable from the raw text.

Comment: @clr, i just opened a saved outlook msg file using a text editor. the file is binary. i did not find any cleartext.

Comment: @jsotola - How odd. There must be different ways this is stored as while much of the mail I looked at was gibberish, the Sender and Date etc. were clearly visible. I see your answer below resolves this anyway, kudos!

Comment: @CLR, i only looked at one that happened to be saved on my desktop .... i just checked again .... and you are right, it is stored in unicode, i think.  every second character is a null ....  deleting the nulls makes the date visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some starting code

```
Option Explicit

Sub getMsgData()

    ' add reference to microsoft outlook object library

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim mailDoc As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Dim nam As Variant
    For Each nam In Array("test.msg", "test2.msg")
        Set mailDoc = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & nam)
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Offset(i) = mailDoc.SentOn
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Offset(i, 1) = mailDoc.Sender
        mailDoc.Close False
        i = i + 1
    Next nam

    olApp.Quit

    Set mailDoc = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```